# Открыть файл с++

Tags: c++

Как открыть файл с именем, заданым в отдельной строке без указания полного пути, только для чтения? В какой директории файл должен находиться?

Answer (score 3):

Файл должен находиться в [**текущем каталоге**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3).

А открыть? Например:

```
ifstream in(fileName);
```

Файл с именем `fileName` открывается для чтения как поток `in`.

Можно добавить флаги - например, рассматривать как бинарный.